# Init properties in my base wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, json, web-config, service

I have set up some WCF services that I use to call from javascript to enable ajax calls such as retrieving data in JSON format.

All my services are configured in a web.config etc and I code in c#.

All my services inherit from a BaseService object which has some common properties that are share between all services, for example a logger object, configuration object etc.

My question is, how/where I can set up/assign values to these properties? ie. set up the base service logger property with an instant of a custom logger I created. Apologies if my question is vague but any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties for Service implementation object cannot be set from client (any kind) because only contract is visible to client. Further, properties such as config and logger are anyway not meant to be part of contract but rather service implementation - so they must get set at server side automatically(i.e. by application infrastructure) for each service object. You have a couple of choices:

1. Use constructor (either that of BaseService or actual service class) to initialize these properties.
2. Use IoC/DependencyInjection container (for example, [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/), [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/))

Comment: Going with IoC approach with spring.net - thanks for your help.